# Help with Business Rule

Tags: biztalk, business-rules

I have a nodeset that contains various number of nodes with unique values. I 
want the rule to fire if the nodeset contains nodes with some of the possible 
values.

Example:
Instance containing a nodeset with one node with Y=1 AND another node with 
Y=2 should fire rule.

Instance that should fire:
- X
- - Y - 1
- - Y - 2
- - Y - 3
- - Y - 4

Instance that should NOT fire:
- X
- - Y - 1
- - Y - 3
- - Y - 4

I tried with AND, OR and others, but the "problem" is that since the engine 
does pattern-matching it tests every node for the condition and it will 
either always fire, or never.

It's not that complex problem. How hard can it be :) When I found "Set of values" I thought I was home safe, but that was more of "enums".Grateful for any suggestion.

Regards
Martin Bring

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines you'll find [here](http://timrayburn.net/blog/timrayburn-customfunctoids-logical-xor/)
It creates an exclusive-OR (When this *or* that *but not* this *and* that) functionality.  Not saying it'll fix it for you, but it may help put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. The post is giving a solution for mappings, with a functoid, I am using Business Rules Engine.

I think I have to create a custom fact that evaluate some kind of "WHERE IN".

Thanks anyway.